# How to wire a patch panel with incomplete labels

Tags: wiring, cat5, networking

I have an used lucent 1100CAT5 PS patch panel that I'm intending to use at my church.

Yes I know, I should probably get a CAT5e version, but this one will do fine.  It's only for light browsing of the internet.  The budget is very tight due to a large building project going on otherwise I'd probably get a Cat5E panel.  Actually the rest of it is 5E anyway.

Anyhow, I'm wanting to use this panel which is in mint condition.

The color codes on the rear are not particularly clear.  Or should I say, they are colored and I can read them fine, but I don't know which side to put the white/blue vs blue wire etc.
i.e. the color markings are solid with a slot either side of it.

A grainy video I watched on youtube with a similar panel looks like the white/blue, white/green etc wires go to the left?  would this be right?

Comment: Just to be clear, I've wired the wall sockets using 568B standard, and the patch panel is marked 568B.  The colors from left to right are blue, orange, green, brown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match my panel.  I'm going to try it on one and put a tester on it to see if it's correct.  It seems likely.

http://www.ehow.com/how_7472794_wire-rj45-patch-panel.html

Comment: Quite sure this is correct.  Just tested which pin was connected to what position with a multimeter and it appears to be wired 568B.  Looks like I punch down as w/b,b,w/o,o,w/g,g,w/br/br

Comment: That isn't really 568B, that is the start of the 25 pair color code: Primary: White, Red, Black, Yellow, Violet. Secondary: Blue, Orange, Green, Brown, Slate.

Comment: But the way the colors are connected to the pins = 568B!

Comment: Works perfectly wired as I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

The pins almost always go in a U-shape around the connector or all 8 in a row. With 1 to 4, then 5 (starting next to 4) to 8 (next to 1). I'm sure there are others, but I've never seen anything else.

```
1 = Orange/White
2 = Orange
3 = Green/White
4 = Blue
5 = Blue/White
6 = Green
7 = Brown/White
8 = Brown
```

Comment: These ones are in a straight line.  Like this vid. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wdDRtGLiow

Comment: Hrm. It does look like its Bl/W, Bl, Or/W, Or, Gn/W, Gn, Br/W, Br. With most modern equipment it will tolerate swapping Or and Gn; I'd try wiring one up and see if it works. I suppose it's strange wiring is most easily explained by its age.

Answer (score 0):

You may find Wikipedia's article on [TIA/EIA-568](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIA/EIA-568#T568A_and_T568B_termination) useful.  Any patch panel I've ever worked with required termination in this order.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a number of different configurations and don't make assumptions or guesses, as that is a sure road to misery.

In a case like this you should try to get the manufacturer's own information. Try their web site or give them a call. If all else fails find a supplier who still stocks them and ask to have a look at the information sheet that comes with the panel. Things may well be different where you are but I can always get the information I need from my local electrical wholesaler. Even if they don't have the item itself they can get the information for me through their suppliers.

Comment: I didn't need to this in the end.  I just got out the multi-meter and worked out which pin was linked to which position on the punchdown section.  I connected one up, plugged in a device and saw that it linked up fine, full speed.

Answer (score 0):

Many older patch panels use the start of the [25 pair color code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/25-pair_color_code) rather than a 568A or 568B configuration. By the sound of it, this is how your panel is laid out.

```
White Blue
Blue
White Orange
Orange
White Green
Green
White Brown
Brown
White Slate
Slate
Red Blue
Blue
Red Orange
Orange
Red Green
Green
Red Brown
Brown
Red Slate
Slate
Black Blue
Blue
Black Orange
Orange
Black Green
Green
Black Brown
Brown
Black Slate
Slate
Yellow Blue
Blue
Yellow Orange
Orange
Yellow Green
Green
Yellow Brown
Brown
Yellow Slate
Slate
Violet Blue
Blue
Violet Orange
Orange
Violet Green
Green
Violet Brown
Brown
Violet Slate
Slate
```

Comment: Actually no.  The panel I have is labeled 568B on the PCB and the front panel.  THe colors cycle brown orange green blue brown orange green blue.  Exactly like that shown in my comment link I attached to Chris S's answer.